# Java How to solve scheduling a calendar

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar

I feel like this is an old and well-known problem but I couldn't find anything on it after searching for a while, i'm probably missing a keyword. Can anyone give me some help/pointers to this problem?

We want to create a calendar schedule where we have 1 person working in each month of the year. There are 12 people and each person picks and ranks their 3 choices of months in a year they want to work. We have to create the most optimal schedule where each person is assigned to a different month in the year. For example,

```
                  david         greg        bob
first choice       dec          dec         mar
second choice      feb          march        may
third choice      april         feb          apr
```

Ignoring the other 9 people, the optimal schedule for these 3 will be: david in feb, greg in dec, bob in march.

There is a points system we can use to decide the order:

3 points    for each volunteer assigned his or her first choice

2 points    for each volunteer assigned his or her second choice

1 point     for each volunteer assigned his or her third choice

0 points    for each volunteer not assigned any of his or her choices

This also must be done using an unsorted list.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: So what you tried so far?

Comment: Brute force strategy: generate every combination and count their points.

Comment: Feeling that greedy algorithm didn't rock. How about dynamic programming?

Comment: I second @keuleJ generate all possible combos, the one with max points should be the best choice.

Comment: Okay, only ~ 456 million combinations, not hard for recent computers.

Comment: Ok there might be a more efficient solution :-) But it would work...

Comment: Sorry I can't brute force it =(  It would be waaay too slow as there would be 12! possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I would say treat this as a version of the stable marriage problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Edit:
Nope, @keuleJ is right. The assignment problem I believe is the correct treatment of this problem. See his comment below.

Perhaps I will come back with an implementation for it later.

Comment: I think it is the assignment problem http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try **dynamic programming and bit mask** for this problem,as we only have 12 people, so we can using 12 bit to represent the state of these people (bit `ith` will be 0 if the `ith` person is not yet been assigned any month and 1 vice versa).

So we try to assign from month to month (from 0 to 11). Java code:

```
int[][]dp;
int maxPoint(int month, int mask)
    if(month == 12)
       return 0;
    if(dp[month][mask] != -1)
       return dp[month][mask];
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       if(((1<<i)&mask) ==0){
          int tmp = maxPoint(month + 1, mask  | (1<<i));
          tmp += numberOfPoint(i, month);//Return 3 if first choice, 2 if second choice...
          result = Math.max(result, tmp);
       }
    return dp[month][mask]=result;
```

Time complexity is 2^12*12*12 operations, which is less than one million operations.